# label and input tags changing row heights. Can do individual div but not all?

Tags: html, css

I can make a label (checkbox) change the properties of a span class to display:block however, it only seems to work for the individual span class and not ALL spans that I have.

I would like to change the height of all li tags so, if the user clicks on just one "details" label, then it will change ALL of the li tags height. See below:

```
<div id="content">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>#1 car is for sale</p>
                <label class="details" for="_1">More details...</label>
                <input id="_1" type="checkbox">
                <span class="row">More elaborate details here</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>#2 car is for sale 2</p>
                <label class="details" for="_2">More details...</label>
                <input id="_2" type="checkbox">
                <span class="row">More elaborate details here</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>#3 car is for sale</p>
                <label class="details" for="_3">More details...</label>
                <input id="_3" type="checkbox">
                <span class="row">More elaborate details here</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#content {
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:1;
text-align:left;
display:block;
}
#content ul{
width:auto;
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
white-space: nowrap;
border:1px solid #00FF00;
}
.details{
display:inline;
width:auto;
color:blue;
}
.details + input{
display:none;
}
.details + input + *{
display:none;
}
.details+ input:checked + *{
display:block;
position:relative;
}
.details+ input:checked + #content ul li{
height:100px;
display:block;
position:relative;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I tried " input:checked + ul li { height:100%; } " and " input:checked + #content ul li { height:100% } " however no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
input:checked + span.row {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```

See it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/98y8whhu/

## EDIT

You can see now the changes. I write a piece of javascript code to make all LI tags same height:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    if(checked) {
        var thisHeight = $(this).parents().find('li').height();
        $('ul > li').height(thisHeight+"px");
    } else {
        $('ul > li').height('auto');
    }
});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/98y8whhu/2/

Comment: Ok I ran it, however it doesn't change the height of ALL the li tags.

Comment: All the `<li>` ? With CSS impossible, and for what you need to change all li tags when check only one checkbox?

Comment: I have several rows and columbs, each contain little links inside of them that say "click for more info". If a user clicks on "more Info", and the row expands in length, I want ALL rows to expand in length so that they all line up with the Top Row-names. So far when the More Info button is clicked, only the single row's length changes, and not the whole table's <li>.

Comment: You need javascript calculations to make this. I don't know why you need this behaviour, it's very strange, but I try to give you a piece of code